# How to convert Faster R-CNN with TensorRT?

Tags: nvidia, object-detection, tensorrt

I'm trying to use TensorRT to speed up my pre-trained model at inference time. Any object detection pre-trained model would work actually, doesn't have to be Faster R-CNN.

I saw that many layers are not supported by TensorRT yet, what would the procedure be in that case? I read that you can implement those layers yourself, but what does that mean? Would I need to retrain my model after "implementing those layers"?

Thanks

Comment: It seems being an official demo of Faster-RCNN in TensorRT: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-developer-guide/index.html#fasterrcnn_sample